# Docker compose network confused the nodes

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-network

Sometimes nginx server forwards request to wrong docker-compose service.

I have docker-compose config

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  proj-reader:
    image: repositry:5000/my-company.com/proj-reader
    ports:
      - "28090:8080"
      - "28095:5005"
  proj-helpdesk:
    image: repository:5000/my-company.com/proj-helpdesk
    ports:
      - "29080:8080"
      - "29085:5005"
  proj-frontend:
    image: repository:5000/my-company.com/proj-frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - "proj-helpdesk:backend"
      - "proj-reader:reader"
...
```

Frontend is a nginx container with NodeJs application. And we have next nginx configuration:

```
upstream backend {
    server backend:8080;
    keepalive 30;
}

upstream reader {
    server reader:8080;
    keepalive 30;
}

server {
    listen     80;
    client_max_body_size 2m;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass          http://backend;
        proxy_read_timeout   600;
    }

    location /web-callback/ {
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass          http://reader;
    }

}
```

And sometimes I can see that request for /web-callback/ is recieved in other service which doesn't pointed in links section for frontend service. At first time I have thougt it happened after I have restarted reader service. But yerstaday this situation repeated and I know that reader haven't been restarted. 
What cn it be? ANd how can I prevent this situation in future?

Comment: use k8s, it's better.

Comment: links are obsolete, use service name -
 https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2831.

Comment: Also use [Embedded DNS server in user-defined networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/) .Within your nginx config `resolver 127.0.0.11;`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use:

```
location ^~ /api/ {
  # Queries beginning with /api/ and then stops searching.
}

location ^~ /web-callback/ {
  # Queries beginning with /web-callback/ and then stops searching.
}
```

https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-location-directive/

Comment: It's not nginx problem. Because it forwrds requests correctly. It's docker networking problem.

Comment: Ok. You can try to check what values you have in /etc/hosts in nginx container and compare it with the ip addresses of the backend and reader containers.